# Unity3D: Can I layer scenes or can I mask scene elements to prevent overlap?

Tags: unity-game-engine

[image: starship bridge scene]

I have a work-in-progress spaceship interior built with Unity (utilizing pre-built assets). It won't move much. The space around it will, similar to how I made an [HTML/Three.js version](https://github.com/owntheweb/cosmic-cruise) of this concept (although linked example does move ship around space scene while scales are also animated).

With the three.js version, I was constantly fighting with "space" entering the ship; warp beams and planets colliding with the front info screen or passing through the chair (destroying the illusion of massive scale). I was able to resolve most issues, but it was a challenge when everything was in the same scene.

In Unity, is there a way to keep the ship scene separate from the surrounding space "scene", whether it is part of the same scene or in a separate one on another layer, or the same scene with masks that prevent overlap? I don't need a very literal answer, but any guidance that leads to a solution will be promptly accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a very basic and useful aspect of Unity - the **layers** system.

As you guess you can find endless doco about it at Unity, cheers

Note too - Unity of course has superb occlusion culling built-in. Almost always this will "just work" for you.

Note that (if I read you right) you're doing a scene with a tremendous difference in scales (like "10 cm" objects AND "1000 km" objects at the same time). As you probably know you basically can't do this in a game engine, it's tricky to pull off.

Just BTW this is more a question for gamedev.com

Comment: Thanks! Yes, that's what I'm thinking now as I keep digging. "occlusion culling" was also a magic phrase in your response that lead to more good reads. I appreciate the feedback!